# Rest Api Design with dependent resources

Tags: rest

I am new to REST API currently i am working on a project where I have 2 resources:

1. Project
2. Client

Now for this did I need to create 2 resource class as given below or a single resource class.

```
@Path("/v1/projects")
public interface ProjectResource {

    @POST
    public Respone add(Project project)

    @DELETE
    public Respone delete(Project project)

    @PUT
    public Respone update(Project project)

}

@Path("/v1/projects/{projectId}/client")
public interface ClientResource {

    @POST
    public Respone add(Client client)

    @DELETE
    public Respone delete(Client client)

    @PUT
    public Respone update(Client client)


}
```

Or a single resource class with all methods

```
@Path("/v1/projects")
public interface ProjectResource {

    @POST
    public Respone add(Project project)

    @DELETE
    public Respone delete(Project project)

    @PUT
    public Respone update(Project project)

    @Path("/{projectId}/client")
    @POST
    public Respone add(Client client)

    @Path("/{projectId}/client")
    @DELETE
    public Respone delete(Client client)

    @Path("/{projectId}/client")
    @PUT
    public Respone update(Client client)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's up to you, but taking [SRP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) into consideration it's better to split the implementation into two classes. Remember that classes should be atomic and focus only on delivering single piece of functionality.